# Problem with / in htaccess file rule and the page load

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have this url: `http://mysite.com/content/14` and this line in htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^content\/([^-]+)$ index.php?m=apple&id=$1 [L,NC,NS]
```

It works OK and show the right page, but with no CSS and JS. CSS & JS files don't load. It is because the `src` of JS files and `href` of CSS files don't start with `/`. They are too many and I can't fix them.

Is there anyway to fix it with some codes in htaccess without need to change other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the client (you browser) thinks that the resource is located on `http://mysite.com/content/14`, making relative URLs resolve to `http://mysite.com/content/`. However, the file is served from `http://mysite.com/`.

If you cannot change the references, you may be able to put in a `<base>` tag (in the HTML — chances are that you can't do that either):

```
<base href="http://mysite.com/" />
```

This goes in the `<head>` section.

Alternatively, make a rewrite for CSS and JS (untested):

```
RewriteRule ^content\/(js|css)\/(.+)$ $1/$2 [L]
```